# Why do I get the error "no `block_on` in `executor`" when attempting to block on an async function?

Tags: rust, async-await

I am following Rust's [async/await primer](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/04_async_await_primer.html) but am having trouble running the hello world program shown below.

```
use futures::executor::block_on;

async fn hello_world() {
    println!("hello, world!");
}

fn main() {
    let future = hello_world(); // Nothing is printed
    block_on(future); // `future` is run and "hello, world!" is printed
}
```

I receive the error:

```
1 | use futures::executor::block_on;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `block_on` in `executor`
```

Is there an import required to use this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Stargateur, `futures = { version = "0.3", features = ["compat"] }` needs to be added to your Cargo.toml dependencies.

The dependency is indicated at the top of [the page following the hello world example](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/05_http_server_example.html).